# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err; when trying to console truffle

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle

[when i used the command truffle console, I got an error stating resolve filename. The error states node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyAXm.png)

Comment: Please, present all related code and show the full error message.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Imagine you are helping someone, how would you help in this question?

Comment: i was performing this code: https://github.com/01Clarian/defi-staking-app-starter, defi staking app starter and in node when i commanded console truffle. At that moment i got the error.

Comment: Paste the code to your question with details please